# swift2 Xcode7.0 Expected ',' separator

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, swift2, xcode7

```
if ( username.isEqualToString("")||
            useremail.isEqualToString("") ||userpassword.isEqualToString("")||
            userphonenumper.isEqualToString("")
            ){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up Failed!", message:"Please enter your data", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: ",ok", style: .Default) { _ in })
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
        }
```

I use Xcode7 and Swift2 when i  run the application I get this error

the error in if statment

```
if ( username.isEqualToString("")||
            useremail.isEqualToString("") ||
```

Comment: You have to add space either to *both* sides of the operator or to *neither*.

Comment: In Swift you need no parentheses at all in (basic) `if` expressions and there is a more convenient `isEmpty` property to check for empty strings.

Comment: What is `this error`?